# Including another join in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

I have created the following query which includes 2 joins:

```
SELECT a.name, b.tid
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id  
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL';
```

The output is coming as follows:

```
id      tid     name
17695   19512   abc.com
17781   19628   abc1.com
17805   19732   abc2.com
17806   19703   abc3.com
17807   19704   abc4.com
```

I have another table table3 which has following values

```
id  tid     name                        details
842 19512   abc.com                     Details Description 1
843 19628   abc1.com                    Details Description 2
```

I want to join the above query with table3 on `tid` such that I get the following output

```
id      tid     name          details      
17695   19512   abc.com       Details Description 1
17781   19628   abc1.com      Details Description 1
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between your actual output and the desired output

Comment: updated my question

Comment: @mealhour Just add another `JOIN` to your query.

Comment: can you please paste the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then it's just an other inner join on table1 a :

```
 SELECT a.id, b.tid, a.name,  table3.details
    FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
         table2 b
         ON a.id = b.id
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
      FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
      GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
      ) t on t.id = a.id  
          AND  t.status=b.status
          AND t.max_time = b.created_time
    INNER JOIN table3 on b.tid = table3.tid
    WHERE b.status = 'FAIL';
```

Comment: Actually, `b.tid` is coming from table2. I have written the following query but it is returning only one row `SELECT a.name, b.tid
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
INNER JOIN table3 T3 on b.tid = T3.tid
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL'`

Comment: with the data given we can't know

Comment: I have changed `INNER JOIN table3 on a.tid = table3.tid` to `INNER JOIN table3 on b.tid = table3.tid` Do you think is there a better way to write this?

Comment: No it's the only way to do INNER JOIN